# redirect command output to variable (bash script)

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

if anyone could shed some light I get this error when I 
include this line in my script

```
find -name "$name" | wc -l >> $num
```

error message $num: ambiguous redirect ?

Comment: Here's a small tip: since you're counting files in current working directory, use `find -mindepth 1 -name "$name"` It will allow you skip `.` , which is working directory itself, that way you have proper count of files.

Answer (score 12):

The syntax

```
find -name "$name" | wc -l >> $num
```

attempts to redirect the output of the pipeline to *a file whose name is contained in the variable* `$num` . The error is likely because `$num` is empty, leaving a dangling redirect operator `>>`

You can't redirect command output to a variable in `bash`; however you can *assign* the output of a command to a variable using [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

```
num=$(find -name "$name" | wc -l)
```

Note that counting lines of output from `find` is not a robust way to evaluate the number of matching files.

Comment: Also note the missing path in the `find` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda what do you mean ?

Comment: @Serg Oh, just that `find` also requires a path to search. The OP didn't specify one. It's an additional problem in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda  If he is searching files in current directory , it's not necessary. At least GNU `find` assumes current path as `.` if it's not given. I don't know about OS X or other *nix systems though

Comment: @Serg Oh, the GNU strikes again.

Comment: It works but eats out `\n` in my output :(

Comment: how are you showing the output? if using `echo`, make sure to use the option `-e` to interpret elements like `\n`